# How to use JsonPath to get first attribute in a structure

Tags: json, groovy, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the following json structure:

```
some_map_like_object: {
    "key_1": {

    },
    "key_2": {

    },
    "key_3" {

    }
}
```

Note that the some_map_like_object is not a collection.

Is there a way to use restassured jsonpath (with gpath) to get the first element in the some_map_like_object?

Answer (score 0):

What I used now and works nicely is:

```
"some_map_like_object.values()[0].some_property"
```